# update profile db with ad but without setting up the ups

Tags: user-profile, profile-sync

Is there another way to push data from Active Directory to profile DB without using UPS. i am working on developer machine and just need one time push from AD to profile DB. Is there an alternate to UPS. The UPS thing on SP2010 RTM is a mess.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you still use SP2010 RTM? You should patch up SharePoint at least to lates service pack. Lots and lots of improvements especially on UPS in those patches. Also what specifically is "a mess" on your system? When configured correctly UPA/UPS/FIM runs very well indeed!

Comment: @AndersRask: But my dev is a single farm with full SQL. I thought SQL needs to be on different server apart from wfe/ca/app/index etc server in order to setup ups.

Comment: I ended up installing SP1 and CU. Then tried the whole thing with UPS and now seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create user profiles programmatically using [UserProfileManager.CreateUserProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.createuserprofile.aspx) method.

You can leverage this method either by using Console Application, or by creating a PowerShell script. I'd prefer the latter approach.

PowerShell code for creating one profile would look something like this:

```
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext http://localhost
$manager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext)

$profile = $manager.CreateUserProfile("domain\helloworld")
$profile.DisplayName = "Hello World"
$profile.Commit()
```

Actually, I've even found a post where a similar script is already implemented:

- http://adisimon.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/powershell-script-to-add-user-profile-in-sharepoint-2010/

This solution will allow you to add user profiles from an XML file. However, obviously it is also possible to pull them from AD.

P.S. I haven't tried this particular script, but recently I used a PowerShell script to populate Organization profiles, and all worked fine.

Comment: so there are few more challenges: 1) Export AD uses with department,etc. in XML 2) Go through xml and make sure it's in correct format.

Comment: Found this link (http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2009/02/11/Powershell-script-to-create-Active-Directory-user-Profiles-and-MySites.aspx) where I should be able to import AD users to SP with powershell. I ran it but keep getting "Multiple ambiguous overloads found for GetUserProfile and the arugument count: 1. $up=$pmanager.GetUserProfile($prop.cn)